# Community extensions usage in enterprise magento

Tags: magento2, page-content

I'm very interested in trying out the [Advanced Content Manager](https://marketplace.magento.com/blackbird-contentmanager.html). But they only have a community edition for sale. Does this mean I can't install it on an enterprise Magento?

Also if anyone has experience with this Content manager I'd love to hear your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community extensions can be installed in Enterprise.